# xamarin.ios load empty uicontrolview before detecting data from webservice

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i'm developing an ios app with xamarin.
i created a button in this way:

```
var myBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
        myBtn.Frame = new CGRect(xImg, 1180, 200, 100);
        myBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Yellow, UIControlState.Normal);
        myBtn.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
        myBtn.TouchUpInside += delegate
        {
            NavController.PushViewController(new WebViewController(), false);
        };
```

the WebViewController contains a webservice call, so it spends some seconds to detect data.
When i Tap on the button, the app calls the webservice first, then it changes the UiViewController.  In this way I can't implement the [Loading Overlay class](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/)

So i need that, when i tap the button, first it shows the empty UiViewController (with the LoadingOverlay), and then, when the webservice call is complete, show the remaining components.

This is the WebViewController:

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        Title = "MyTitle";

        var logo = new UIImageView(new CGRect(20, 50, sizes.Width - 40, 130));
        logo.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("logo.jpg");
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

            scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(20, 180, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 40, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 180));
            scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            .........
            List<UIImage> imagesList = getImagesList(urlG);
            int count = 0;
            List<UIImageView> imageViewList = new List<UIImageView>();
            List<UIButton> btnList = new List<UIButton>();
            nfloat imgS = getImgSizes();
            nfloat imgY = 0;
            ......
            for (int i = 0; i < imageViewList.Count; i++)
            {
                scrollView.AddSubview(imageViewList[i]);
                scrollView.AddSubview(btnList[i]);
            }
            scrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 40, ((imagesList.Count / 4) * getImgSizes()) + 150);
            View.AddSubview(logo);
            Add(scrollView);
            View.Add(loadPop);
            .....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you blocking the main thread in `ViewDidLoad` until your web service call finishes? I don't see anywhere in your button code that would make it wait before pushing the next view controller.

Comment: Use async await in your data loading.

Comment: @Rohit i'm new in xamarin, could you explain it better what you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/